# Ecto preload nested

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am learning phoenix and ecto associations but I have stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to solve while trying to preload nested associations. I have 3 schemas

Offer that has

```
schema "offers" do
    ...
    has_one :albumMariageSmall, Album, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete
    has_one :prewedding, Prewedding, on_delete: :delete_all, 
    on_replace: :delete
    has_one :next_day, Prewedding, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete
end
```

Now, the Prewedding looks like

```
schema "preweddings" do
    ...
    has_one :album, Album, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete
end
```

and the album looks like

```
schema "albums" do
    ...
    belongs_to :offer, Offer
    belongs_to :prewedding, Prewedding
end
```

In other words, an offer can have an Album and two Prewedding which Prewedding can have an Album.

Database wise, the :preweddings is referencing the offer through offer_id and the :albums references the offers through offer_id and the preweddings through prewedding_id.

I have trouble loading any saved offer as both :prewedding and :next_day seem point to the same row when I am inspecting.

I am trying to preload using

```
offer=Repo.one from(o in Offer, preload: [{:prewedding, [:album]},{:next_day, [:album]}], select: o, where: o.id==^id)
```

I assume I can make it work with joins, but i am stubborn enough to want to do preload.

Can someone assist?

Migration of preweddings is just this

```
add :included, :boolean, default: false, null: false
add :offer_id, references(:offers)
```

Album has

```
add :offer_id, references(:offers)
add :prewedding_id, references(:preweddings)
```

Comment: Can you post your migrations of "preweddings"? You probably need to specify a custom `foreign_key` for the two `has_one` in "offers" or they both will point to the `offer_id` column.

Comment: mmm there are no custom foreign keys and when i tried, i added to the album (references). Let me see.

Comment: Well, you need two columns in preweddings pointing to offers if you want two `has_one` that do the same. Right now both are using `offer_id` which means both have identical values.

Comment: I am not quite sure i got it neither how to implement this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, got it! Your comments made me understand, eventually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when using `has_one`, the foreign key is inferred from the name of the current table, e.g. `offers` -> `offer_id`. Since you have two `has_one` and you don't specify a custom foreign key for either, both will use `offer_id` as the foreign key and will therefore always have the same value. You'll need to specify the correct foreign keys to the two `has_one`. For example, if your `preweddings` table has this migration:

```
add :offer_prewedding_id, references(:offers)
add :offer_next_day_id, references(:offers)
```

You need to do:

```
has_one :prewedding, Prewedding, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete, foreign_key: :offer_prewedding_id
has_one :next_day, Prewedding, on_delete: :delete_all, on_replace: :delete, foreign_key: :offer_next_day_id
```